# Particle system clipping

Tags: game-engine, monodevelop, unity-game-engine

In the picture below, I have set up a cloud particle system using the particle duststorm material from the standard assets pack. Upon playing, the particles are being clipped in the distance instead of showing the edge of the cloud creating a harsh separation from the clouds and the sky. Is this fixable?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried increasing the camera far clipping plane?

Comment: Oh wow. That was it. Sat there for a good 3 hours trying to figure it out.

Comment: I will make it an answer so that this question could be closed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because of your camera far clipping plane. Default value is 1000. Increasing it should fix the problem.

[image]